# Specify voice in twilio actions json

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

In one of my situations I need to be able to specify the voice in the default initiation of the autopilot. I have a strange behavior. Despite the style sheet set to a particular voice, the default initiation is not using that voice. Instead it is using may be a default voice? I don't know. However when the next intent is detected the voice switches to the correct voice specified in the style sheet.

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "say": "Hello , May I speak to Mr Peter ?"
        },
        {
            "listen": true
        }
    ]
}
```

My Style sheet

```
{
    "style_sheet": {
        "voice": {
            "say_voice": "Polly.Raveena"
        },
    [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation says: "You can enter any of the en-US voices listed in the [Text-to-Speech documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech#polly-standard-and-neural-voices)." `Polly.Raveena` is `en-IN` so this might cause your issue. Have you tried with a `en-US` voice? Does the same happen?

Comment: Hello @yvesonline , I was earlier using another en-IN voice Polly.Aditi and the flow was fine . Only with this voice it's having trouble . I have to admit that this voice was more convincing that than Polly.Aditi .

Comment: I would recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) as sounds like something is going wrong with the voice selection.